# Can't deploy my project to Jboss 7.2 WildFly(WeldStartService Failed to start service)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss, wildfly

I'm a noob user of Jboss 7.2(WildFly) and I have this project to deploy I named it "project.war" on the log displayed below. This project works fine on Jboss 7.1.3 but when importing it to 7.2 I get this exception. Thanks in advance to anyone who will help!

```
12:09:37,259 DEBUG [org.infinispan.util.ModuleProperties] (MSC service thread 1-13) No module lifecycle SPI classes available
12:09:37,282 DEBUG [org.infinispan.util.ModuleProperties] (MSC service thread 1-13) Loading module command extension SPI class: org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.util.CacheCommandExtensions@2903eb41
12:09:37,283 DEBUG [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (MSC service thread 1-13) Started cache manager ISPN on null
12:09:40,735 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1900) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000818 Event type class org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl is not allowed
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:187)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.checkEventObjectType(ObserverNotifier.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:673)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.fireEvent(ForwardingBeanManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.XmlConfigExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(XmlConfigExtension.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:240)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:37)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    ... 3 more

12:09:40,761 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-9) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "project.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000818 Event type class org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl is not allowed
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:187)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.checkEventObjectType(ObserverNotifier.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:673)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.fireEvent(ForwardingBeanManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.XmlConfigExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(XmlConfigExtension.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:240)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
"}}
12:09:40,772 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-9) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "project.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"project.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000818 Event type class org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl is not allowed
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier$EventTypeCheck.load(ObserverNotifier.java:187)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.checkEventObjectType(ObserverNotifier.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:673)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.fireEvent(ForwardingBeanManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.XmlConfigExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(XmlConfigExtension.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:240)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
"}}
12:09:40,788 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Tactical Nuclear Penguin' 5.3.0.Final
12:09:40,884 DEBUG [org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Using JBoss Marshalling
12:09:40,913 DEBUG [org.infinispan.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Using JBoss Marshalling
12:09:40,920 DEBUG [org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Interceptor chain size: 6
12:09:40,920 DEBUG [org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Interceptor chain is: 
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
12:09:40,925 DEBUG [org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Object name jboss.infinispan:type=Cache,name="local-query(local)",manager="hibernate",component=Cache already registered
12:09:40,925 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
12:09:40,928 DEBUG [org.infinispan.CacheImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Started cache local-query on null
12:09:40,977 DEBUG [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (MSC service thread 1-6) Stopping cache manager ISPN on null
12:09:40,983 DEBUG [org.infinispan.CacheImpl] (MSC service thread 1-6) Stopping cache local-query on null
12:09:40,985 DEBUG [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionTable] (MSC service thread 1-6) Wait for on-going transactions to finish for 30 seconds.
12:09:40,985 DEBUG [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionTable] (MSC service thread 1-6) All transactions terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a noob too with JBoss, but I've been working with CDI, Weld and Seam/Solder.

The problem (which I'm facing too) is an incompatibility between CDI 1.1 (Weld-2.x implementation) and Solder lib (`org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl`). If you don't use directly Solder, I recomend you to exclude it from deployment. Else,... I don't know as [Solder has been discontinued](http://seamframework.org/Seam3) and even recomend to use [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org), but although it has been graduated, IMHO it is not enough mature,....

Comment: To be honest, I'm not missing something from Solder in CDI1.1, do you?

Comment: Yes, I miss a few, but also from Seam: **Seam-International**, properties i18n; **Seam-Faces**, `s:viewAction` and `FacesContext` production; **Solder-Catch** (exception control) and `HttpServletResponse` production.
But the main problem is the migration of all this functionality to DeltaSpike is not documented (and in fact, it is very poor documented DeltaSpike,...).

Comment: Thanks for the help @mabi, I was able to deploy now my project, but, I had to move to JBoss EAP 6.1 for it to deploy.  Thanks for letting me know that it wasn't compatible, gave me a little bit better understanding of how things work.